# Why I am getting Django page not found error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I am not understanding why I am getting this `Page not found (404) Raised by:django.views.static.serve` here is my code:

**app views.py:**

```
class SESmail(TemplateView):
      template_name = 'mail/account_confirmation.html'
```

**app urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('confirmmail/',SESmail.as_view(), name='confirmmail'),

  ]
```

**root urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
   #my others url....
    path('', include('sesmail.urls')),
    
]+static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**settings.py:**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [ 
 ....
  'sesmail',
]


STATIC_URL = 'https://%s/%s/' % (AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN, AWS_LOCATION)
```

I am not understanding why I am getting this error? I added app name in my settings.py and also added url configuration properly in app urls.py and root urls.py. Where I am doing wrong?

Comment: what is `MEDIA_ROOT` in your `settings.py`

Comment: @mrash Thanks mash I was commented my media root.

Comment: you are used `MEDIA_ROOT` and `MEDIA_URL`. the problem may be related to this. You can comment plus in root urls.py to test this effect.

Comment: @boyenec this is happening on local server or on production server

Answer (score 0):

the error was happening because I commented my media root

```
#MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
#MEDIA_ROOT =  os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

After uncomment the problem is solved. if you are using `+static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_URL)` in your root urls.py then you might be get this error again. Add `settings.STATIC_ROOT`  instead of using `settings.STATIC_URL`

Answer (score 0):

Change your app `urls.py` into the following:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('',SESmail.as_view(), name='confirmmail'),

  ]
```